# Push JSON item in to existing array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've got a JSON array i'm loading from localstorage which I want to add more items to and put back in local storage. However, i'm getting a bit lost and an error saying concat doesn't exist.

```
 $scope.searchObj = {
      term: searchTerm
    };

    $scope.curObj = $scope.curObj.concat($scope.searchObj);

    localStorage.setObject('searchObj', $scope.curObj);
```

$scope.curObj currently looks like:

```
Object {term: "fs"}
```

And I'd like to push the searchTerm (in searchObj) in to curObj so it looks like

```
{"term":"fs","term":"searchterm"}
```

Comment: I would convert it into an array, then merge both arrays and then convert it back into an object.

Comment: the thing you are missing is You are not converting it into array  push works with only Array so ... simple thing missing

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.searchObj` is not an array but a `JSON` object.

You actually want to merge two objects. You can use in plain JS :

```
for (var attrname in $scope.curObj) { 
       $scope.searchObj[attrname] = $scope.curObj[attrname]; 
     }
```

Or by using  [angular extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
$scope.searchObj = angular.extend($scope.searchObj, $scope.curObj);
```

Comment: For future users: `angular.extend` does not support recursive deep copy - use `angular.merge` for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ngStorage` for storing object into localstorage and use service `$localStorage` - 
   [Reference](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)
2. Use angular.extend(oldobject,newobject) for merging